# undefined method `call' for 0.3576657234101671:Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my configuration of my aplication_controller [sic].

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
def disappeareds
  disappeared_id = params[:disappeared_id]
  if(disappeared_id.nil?)
    relation = Relation.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    sorteio = rand.(0...relation.size)
    @disappeared = Disappeared.where(id: relation[sorteio].disappeared_id).take
  else
    @disappeared = Disappeared.where(id: disappeared_id).take
  end
end
end
```

I came across this method error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `call' for 0.3576657234101671:Float:
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `disappeareds'
  app/controllers/mains_controller.rb:4:in `index`
```

Comment: Given `prc = ->(x) { ... }` (or some other `Proc`), you can say `prc.(6)`, `prc[6]`, and `prc.call(6)` to execute `prc` and [**`prc.()` invokes `prc.call()` with the parameters given. It's syntactic sugar to hide `call`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D), hence the confusing error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `.`

Move from

```
sorteio = rand.(0...relation.size)
```

to

```
sorteio = rand(0...relation.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

only went to another line

`TypeError - no implicit conversion from nil to integer:
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in`disappeareds'
  app/controllers/mains_controller.rb:4:in `index'`